# Swift Input and event handling for storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode-storyboard

I've been trying to outline the basic functionality of a swift application I was developing.  I created a basic gui with the storyboard functionality that xcode provides.  Here is a picture of what it looks like currently:
[image]

What I want to do next is code up a way to receive and store input from the text fields I outlined in the storyboard.  Additionally I want to receive information regarding certain settings that are placed from the switches I outlined in the second screen.

I've been looking through the files that xcode provides me but I haven't been able to find the one that contains the functionality for the storyboards.  If someone could point me in the right direction for that i would greatly appreciate it.  Ultimately I just want to be able to manage the input provided by the interface I outlined below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For each view controller on the storyboard make a subclasses of  `UIViewController`.
2. In the inspector panel on the left of the storyboard set the class of each view controller to their respective subclass of `UIViewController`.
3. Open up the .swift file for that view controller and storyboard and ctrl + drag from the textField to the class this will cause a small popup where you can create an IBOutlet or IBAction.